# create a rewrite for files from cache dir to web on-fly

Tags: symfony, url-rewriting

I have a bundle and this generate (in cache dir) two file types (.txt and png). i know i can save this files in the web dir (but this is not the desired behavior).

I need rewrite files onfly like AsseticBundle but I failed to understand how it does that bundle.

Basically what I want is:

```
-from: "%kernel.cache_dir%/generator/09/55/68b472475bc33455b71b6900c291.png"
-to  : "/img/09/55/68b472475bc33455b71b6900c291.png"
```

without copy file, just like AsseticBundle

```
{% stylesheets
    'bundles/mybundle/bootstrap.css'
    'bundles/mybundle/app.css'
    output='css/style.css'
%}
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset_url}}">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Comment: Write a controller which will catch urls like `/img/{token}` and return images as a response

Comment: a simple symlink is not an option?

Comment: @forgottenbas I thought about that, but it has performance penalty?

Comment: @rkmax of course. Web server process files faster than php interpreter